# {N} +Angular-2 http post returns null in the body but status is 200

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular2-nativescript, angular2-observables

I'm working with {N}+Angular 2. I'm making a Http POST call to a remote API. When I'm trying to run the API on the App, it returns a response with status 200 but a null body.

However,  When I test the API on POSTMAN, it gives the body. Once I test the API on postman and run it on my application, it returns the body in the response. Please help me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Please go through rxjs , observable and all you Will get an idea

Comment: If you show your code it would help us help you. Please show your post request and wherever you are handling the response.

Answer (score 0):

Angular AJAX calls are initially Observables. Did you turn your Observable into a Promise?

Reading through this part of the tutorial on the Angular website should help, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of making a POST request and then handling the response by subscribing to it.

**Post Request**

```
 MakePostRequest() {
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return this.http
                .post('http://localhost:4200/api/end-point',
                    model,
                    {headers: headers})
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    //do something with the response here
                    console.log(res);
                });
        }
    }
```

Make sure that you are adding the correct port. If you are using a node server then most likely the port should be the same you are running the ng2 app on. But if you are using a PHP server than the port will be whatever your PHP server is running on.

So in my case my `apache` is running on `port 80`. In that case I would change the `URL` to this,

```
.post('http://localhost:80/api/end-point',
```

This is a `Get Request`

**Get Request**

```
 public GetRequest() {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('email', this.user.email);// set params to URL
    params.set('api_key', this.apiKey); // set params to URL

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:80/api/end-point',
        { search: params })
          .map((res: Response) => res.json())
          .subscribe((res) => {
              console.log(res);
          });
  };
```

Also make sure you have the correct imports in your component.

```
import {Http, Response, Headers, URLSearchParams}         from '@angular/http';
```

You sound like you are on a path which will bring you to observables soon. Remember when you embark upon using observables you will need to use the `rxjs` module. When using observables you typically would need this import but than again many more from `rxjs`.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
```